# Employing caching for the first page of a paginated view in Django

Tags: python, django, caching, pagination, memcached

I have a paginated Django forum where posts by users accumulate according to most recent time of posting. I show 20 posts per page. At peak time, a new post is saved every ~2 seconds, whereas pages are requested for viewing up to 11 times per second.

I want to reduce DB hits by introducing caching. I've noticed most of the traffic hits the first page - so this is the one I want to cache. Essentially, I plan to `set` the first page in the cache at each write, and `get` it whenever viewers want to consume it. I have the options of `redis` and `memcache` as a cache backend.

My question is how to cache and serve **just the first page**. My uncached code is as follows:

```
#object_list has up to 1000 object ids at a time
paginator = Paginator(object_list, 20) #pass list of obj ids & no. of objs/page
page = request.GET.get('page', '1')
try:
    page = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    page = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
page_contents = retrieve_posts(page.object_list) #retrieve 20 objects
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will attempt to check the cache if the page number is one. If it's not found, a request will be made to the database.

```
page = request.GET.get('page', '1')
if page == '1':
    cached_page = cache.get('cached_page',None)
    if cached_page:
        return cached_page

#object_list has up to 1000 object ids at a time
paginator = Paginator(object_list, 20) #pass list of obj ids & no. of objs/page
try:
    page = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    page = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

page_contents = retrieve_posts(page.object_list) #retrieve 20 objects
if page == '1':
    cache.set('cached_page',page_contents)
```

It's not clear what your queryset is like. But unless you have compelling evidence to show that this is a slow query, this is premature optimization. Retrieving items from the database using primary keys is very fast. Since you have to invalidate your cache twice per second, that overhead might make it not worth the effort.

Comment: Hey there! I'll try it out and get back to you with precise benchmarks and such. Indeed, cache invalidation might be a bottleneck here. I was wondering whether memcached or redis are suited for microcaching of this sort.

Comment: memcached is probably better

Comment: Since that's multi-threaded, could there be any risk of race conditions in this particular scenario?

Comment: with caching there is always the possibility of race conditions. Caching should only be used when race conditions don't matter

Comment: I'm planning on updating a key in the cache on each write. And then just using `cache.get()` to retrieve the cached data whenever it's demanded (like you've pointed out too). So technically, this pattern shouldn't result in anything untoward, no?

Comment: actually it would. The proper way is to delete the item from the cache **before** the write. Even then there isn't any guarantee because the cache and the RDBMS are two different servers, one cannot ensure atomicity in such situations